# UIStackview not honoring hugging priority

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a view that should look as follows

```
---------------
|      A       |
---------------
|      B       |
|              |
----------------
|              |
|       C      |
|              |
----------------
```

view A and view C is the same custom view with different details that should influence its height.
However, when I put them into a stack view, I get three equally proportioned views instead of different height views.

I tried all the possible settings of the stack view.

How do I make it work ?

Comment: I know you tried many setups, but it's always good to share an iteration of the code you tried and similar SO posts you saw. Can you please do that?

Comment: Have you set a height or top/bottom constraints for your stack view? Did you set its Distribution to Fill Proportionally? Are you adding views in code or in Storyboard / Interface Builder?